# Generic Inquiry as Primary List/Entry Point

Tags: acumatica

As I build custom entry screens for our business requirements, an objective is to utilize generic inquiries as the entry point for a consistent user experience with the rest of the system. I have 3 user entry screens, each of which is on the Site Map in the same place. Two of the GI's allow me to select the Site Map node for these user screens and assign the Entry Point to display the GI instead of the user entry screen. One does not. All of them appear to have very similar DAC structure as well as Graph structure including naming the primary graph in the DAC.

What causes the site map node to be available (or not) for assignment of the GI as an entry point. (For instance, is there an orphaned record I might seek out in SQL from deleting a previous attempt?)

I am on Acumatica ERP 2018R1 (Build 18.113.0018).

Comment: go to your page and then under help click web service. Do you get any errors? This is how i usually find out if a screen is not allowed for selection in an import/export scenario. i don't think it would be the same issue but something to check on

Comment: From the Entry Screen that I cannot select for the Entry Screen in my GI, no errors on the Web Services link.  I drilled into each option, and those all looked normal.

Comment: Between user entry screen and entry point on the GI "entry screen" there are too many entry screen references here!  I checked web services on my CRUD screen that I want to build a GI entry screen as a primary list.  No errors that I could see.  Nothing in a trace either.

Comment: Is the primary view a filter? i don't think those can be used with a GI entry list. Look at the keys or primary view as a possible issue. Other than that I am not much help here sorry

Comment: It is not a filter, but there could be something to the keys.  My other 2 GI's are against tables that the primary key is a string field that is populated from my 3rd table that won't seem to work as expected.  My troublesome GI is based on a DAC defined with an identity key and a string used as a numbering sequence.  That string is what the other 2 tables hold as their primary keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of issues that prevented the Generic Inquiry from allowing it to be set as an Entry Point.  If you have this same issue, review the related DAC's carefully for errors that may not be compile time issues.  Also, double check all of the definition tabs in the generic inquiry for fields that you renamed or dropped but failed to adjust in the GI.  In my case, the last issue resolved that allowed the GI to be turned into an entry screen was a poorly defined parameter.

To troubleshoot, try making the GI very simple.  If you cannot reach the screen to select as the entry point and the GI is very basic, odds are that you have a problem somewhere in the DAC. In some of the DAC's for screens that I could not setup as an entry point, I had reference to a setup DAC that was not using Currrent when it should.  This small error in the DAC was the problem on 2 of my 3 screens.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the primary view name in the graph was not 100% the same as the datamember on the screen. One was camelcase and the other pascal case. Make sure the view name on both the screen and the graph is exactly the same.